# react : how to define a variable in jsx and use it in the code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

in the react JSX code, there is a situation in that I want to loop over the object and display the key and value,

The object is returned by calling a function.

so, to loop over the object I am using `Object.keys`,

but to access the value of the object key, I need to refer to the object, but I don't want to call the function again to get the object since there is some processing involved.

```
Object.keys(dpsData = this.getDpsData(this.state.selectedComponentData)).map(key => 
(<div className="componentStatus">
        <div className="metaDataKey">{key}</div>
        <div className="metaDataValue">{dpsData[key]}</div>
</div>))
```

Ss there any way to temporarily store the object in a variable in JSX code?
and not using any global, state/variable

Comment: Why not just save the value to a variable outside JSX?

Comment: ya, we can do that, but this object is just needed here, just thinking if possible, not to create any global object,

Comment: You can't write assignments in JSX because they get transformed to function calls. `Object.entries` might be helpful in this case. Or just use a variable.

Comment: It won't be global if you don't make it global. Creating a local variable outside the JSX block is exactly the same thing as somehow creating one inside, if that even were possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the function call in the JSX for some reason, then you can instead of `Obect.keys`, use `Object.entries`, which gives you access to both key and value, it would look like this:

```
Object.entries(this.getDpsData(this.state.selectedComponentData)).map(([key, value]) => {
return (<div className="componentStatus">
        <div className="metaDataKey">{key}</div>
        <div className="metaDataValue">{value}</div>
</div>)
})
```